# What's the point of "var t = Object(this)" in the official implementation of forEach?

Tags: javascript

[According to the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the ECMA-262, 5th edition gives the implementation of forEach as:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
    }
  };
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the line "var t = Object(this)" is doing? How does Object(this) differ from plain this? And what work is that difference doing here?

Comment: Never seen `void 0` used like that before either...

Comment: `this === void 0 || this === null` could be written like so: `this == null`... same thing.

Comment: I guess so that if you call `Array.prototype.forEach.apply(123, function() {})` it does not throw an error, because the `in` would normally not be defined for numbers.

Comment: @cwolves No, it doesn't. `value == null` evaluates to true only for the cases where `value` is `undefined` or `null`, and **not** for all falsy values.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Apologies, you're correct :)

Comment: I think @pimvdb is right. It seems to be something to handle primitive values.

Comment: FYI, `void 0` is a safe `undefined` since `undefined=42` is valid code.

Comment: @cwolves ES5-compliant implementations don't allow to overwrite value of `undefined`. I'm sure about IE9, don't know about others.

Comment: I like that they're calling for fun. (`fun.call(...)`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Mozilla implementations just try to emulate exactly the steps that are described in the specification, `Object(this);` emulates the *first step*, calling the [`ToObject`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9) internal method:

From  `Array.prototype.forEach` [15.4.4.18](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18):

> ....
>
> When the forEach method is called with
>   one or two arguments, the following
>   steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be the result of calling
>      ToObject passing the this value as the
>      argument.
> 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length".
> 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
>
> ....

Calling [the Object constructor as a function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.1) behind the scenes it performs type conversion, internally as described in [15.2.1.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.1.1) the `ToObject` method is called.

There are more things like this if you look carefully, for example, the line:

```
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

They are emulating a call to the [ToUint32](http://es5.github.com/#x9.6) internal method, as described in the step 3, using the unsigned right shift operator ([`>>>`](http://es5.github.com/#x11.7.3)).

**Edit:**
The previous lines answer *why* the Mozilla implementation does it in this way.

You might wonder why the ECMAScript spec. needs to call `ToObject`, check back the *Step 2*, and it will start to seem obvious:

> 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length".

The spec. needs to ensure that the `this` value used when the function is called is *an object*, because primitive values don't have any internal methods, an as you can see on the step 2, the `[[Get]](P)` internal method is needed, to get the value of the `length` property.

This is done because for *strict functions* (and also for built-in functions), you can set *primitive values* as the function's `this` value, e.g.:

```
(function () {"use strict"; return typeof this; }).call(5); // "number"
```

While for non-strict functions, the `this` value is always converted to Object:

```
(function () { return typeof this; }).call(5); // "object"
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the annotated ES5. That'll be very handy!

Comment: you're still just answering _what_ rather than _why_ .

Comment: @Alnitak, I've answered *why* the *Mozilla implementation* of `forEach` calls the `Object` constructor as a function. But since you want the answer about *why* the *ECMAScript specificacion* uses `ToObject` on the description of the forEach method, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: that would be good - I don't think _"because the spec says so"_ is what the OP was after.

Comment: +1 You're the nuts when it comes to JS. I've lost count of the amount of times I've read your replies. Thanks man.

Comment: @Alnitak That is to say, `var t = Object(this);` allows you to call `var len = t.length >>> 0;` (specifically the `t.length` part) without worry. If, for some strange reason, `this` was `5`, `5.length` would, obviously, blow up. An object will return `undefined` for properties it "doesn't have"/aren't defined. Interesting extrapolations... `Object(5) === 5` is false, and `Object(5) == 5` is true. Oh, and `Object(5).length >>> 0;` is `0`. A little hipster, but pretty cool, right?

Answer (score 5):

The probable reason is [s9.9](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9) of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), about the abstract  *`ToObject`* operation (as mentioned by @CMS).

When called on `null` or an `undefined` value it forces the throwing of a `TypeError`, but those are already trapped by the previous lines.

However if you were to call:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call("123", func() { ... } )
```

this would fail if it weren't for the type coercion.   In particular you can't call `index in this` if `this` is a `string`, but you *can* call it on the result of *`ToObject`*.

This text from [15.4.4.18](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18) is probably relevant:

> The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

Comment: They test for `undefined` and `null` beforehand anyway.

Comment: While `null` and `undefined` throw a `TypeError` when given to `ToObject`, that's not the case for `Object`, hence the previous check. With respect to *"...you can't call `index in this` if `this` is a `string`..."*, that doesn't seem to be correct. The [specification requires](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) that a `for-in` does its own call to `ToObject`, which is why you can do `for( var i in "123" ) {...}`

Comment: @patrick this isn't a `for ... in` call, it's an `if ( ... in ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

I write `var t = this;` all the time. I find that the scope of this is sometimes browser-dependent; in any case it's not always clear what a browser is going to do with the keyword this as scope changes, especially in method closures.  I like to dumb down my JS code to a kindergarten level to leave minimal room for individual browsers to do wonky things.

To ensure that I'm always dealing with the `this` I want to be dealing with when passing `this` to a method or something, I always write `var t = this;` as the first line of my method. Then, `t` is a variable and obeys predictable variable scope rules, and its pointer is assigned at assignment time to the object denoted by this at that time. This way I don't have to worry about a method, other object, or noncompliant browser reinterpreting what `this` refers to in scope.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which was specifically about the odd `var t = Object(this);`, which is essentially type-casting `this` as an Object, which `this` should always be. What you're describing is just the common practice we see as `var _this = this;` or `var self = this;` everywhere. Even the popular opinion on that is changing now that people are becoming more accustomed to FP best-practices and the proper use of `Function.prototype.bind()`