# What does Object(this) do?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, shim

I noticed in several MDN Array method shims, such as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on line 7, that they use the following syntax:

```
var t = Object(this);
```

Where `this` is an array. Not only does it not hint in my validator, I’m also clueless as to what it does.

Can anyone shed a light?

Comment: Isn't that something like copy constructors in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the point of "var t = Object(this)" in the official implementation of forEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498487/whats-the-point-of-var-t-objectthis-in-the-official-implementation-of-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only use of it in there is to cover the case when you pass a string literal to `Array.prototype.indexOf`. If you remove it and pass a string in you get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in string

However, by casting the string literal to an instance of `String`, you end up with an object with a numerical property for each character of the string, and since it's a normal object, you can use the `in` operator on it and the method will return the index of the character in the string:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call("hello", "e"); // Returns 1
```

Here's [an example with the cast to `Object`](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8WhH/1/), and here's [an example without it](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8WhH/2/).

---

In more general cases, passing anything to the `Object` constructor will attempt to convert that thing to an object. So you can pass it a string literal and get an instance of `String` back, or pass it a numeric literal and get an instance of `Number`.

Comment: It wouldn't have worked for any boolean, number, `null` or `undefined` as well - basically every primitive value.

Comment: @Bergi - I'm not entirely sure what the reason for that code was... it's not in the polyfill [currently on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill). I vaguely remember researching it for this answer but that was obviously a while ago now.

Comment: Yeah, [MDN is a wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf$history?limit=all).